# Disable Quicklook for certain filetypes

Tags: macos, finder, memory, quicklook

We have a few Mac's that choke on folders that have a lot of .TIFF files in them.  The quicklookd process, and Quicklook Helper processes skyrocket in RAM and CPU usage.

I'd like to keep quicklook from trying to generate previews for TIFF files, and found this helpful post:  [How do I keep QTKitServer (QuickLook Helper) CPU usage from exploding out of control? OR How do I disable QuickLook entirely?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52994/how-do-i-keep-qtkitserver-quicklook-helper-cpu-usage-from-exploding-out-of-con) but it states at the top of that file, that:

```
    "..... The contents of this file are also auto-generated and
;;;;;; not user editable; it may be overwritten at any time."
```

So, this is a temp fix at best.  I could always script something up which copies back our modified file during bootup, but I am wondering if there's another way to go about this.

Right now, this users' Mac is unusable right now when viewing these files in the Finder.  The RAM usage quickly spirals out of control (almost immediately jumping to 4GB) and then the paging to disk starts, which bogs the whole machine down.

Also, this post is linked to in the think different post:  http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1463364

Comment: You should file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com. Looking at a folder in the Finder should definitely not eat 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? 9 years later And I'm having the same problem... :(